# What is an adjective for "almost, but not entirely correct"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective, and I'll use an example to describe what I'm looking for.

John says: *"It is impossible to stand on one hand."*

When in reality, it is *unimaginably difficult* (one might also say, *statistically impossible*) to stand on one hand.* John's statement isn't necessarily *wrong*, it's just incorrectly "rounded off" the slightest amount, and "technically correct, but not completely".

Someone pedantic could correct John, saying: *"Your statement is ***_*__*_***."*

Comment: * _I honestly have no idea if anyone has succeeded in standing on one hand; I simply picked something that sounded near-impossible for the example._

Comment: Why not try "flawed"?

Comment: Some people would use **wrong** for this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following terms.
• *[unsound](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unsound#Adjective)*, “Not sound; not whole; not solid; defective”
• *[unsafe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unsafe#Adjective)*, in its legal sense of not being shown beyond the shadow of a doubt
• *[debatable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/debatable#Adjective)*, “Controversial. Not fully proved, open to debate”
• *[controvertible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/controvertible#Adjective)*, “Open to questioning; that which can be denied, challenged, or disputed”

Use *unsafe* if talking with legally versed people in the UK.  Use *debatable* if you wish to suggest the topic is open to discussion.  Use *controvertible* if you want a simple word that is uncommon and correct: it asserts that exceptions to some assertion exist, without denying that the assertion is true of many cases.

Answer (score 1):

'[Close](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/close?show=0&t=1387824950)' would be the simplest means of this as 'almost-but-not-quite' in many circumstances. For an attempt or action that nearly but doesn't actually succeed or do what was intended might be considered a [near miss](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/near%20miss), or false-start.

Or to fully quote webster's synonyms for '[Almost](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/almost)'

> about, all but, borderline, fair [chiefly British], fairly, feckly [chiefly Scottish], more or less, most, much, near, nearly, next to, nigh, practically, somewhere, virtually, well-nigh, as good as, just about, pretty much, within an inch of

Comment: As in "close, but no cigar!" :-)